# can two python programs write and read a same HDF5 file at same time

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have 2 python programs:

> **1)data reciever**: It's a TCP SERVER writen in tornado,about 3,000 rows of data will be sent to it every second. here is the hander:

```
def _on_data_rev(data_list):
    tickstore_file=r"d:\data\2016_01_11.h5"
    tempdf=pd.DataFrame(data_list)
    hdf_output = pd.HDFStore(tickstore_file, complib='blosc')
    hdf_output['_'+str(int(time.time()))]=tempdf
    hdf_output.flush()
```

The data comes very fast, so this program only do save job, but nothing else.

> 2)**data analysis**:program 2 will analysis the lastest data on the same file **every second**

Can I read the HDF5 file at the same time? will this destory the HDF5 file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your looking for is the Single Writer Multiple Reader (SWMR) feature of HDF5.

SWMR is listed as [new](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/docNewFeatures/NewFeaturesSwmrDocs.html) in the [1.10](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtain5110.html) release and has a fair bit of [documentation](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/docNewFeatures/SWMR/UG-HDF5-SWMR-20130629-v3.pdf) on it.

It is also in [h5py](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/swmr.html) with version 2.5.0.

As for support in pandas, I am not too sure as I don't use it.